# Get public key from private key in Bouncy Castle C#

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

So I have an encrypted private key PEM.  I can read it and get the private key with the following:

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter key;
using (var sr = new StringReader(pem))
using (var pf = new PassowrdFinder { Password = password })
{
  var reader = new PemReader(sr, pf);
  key = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)reader.ReadObject();
}
```

I also need the public key, to create the SPKI later on.  I tried

```
var keyPair = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(key, key);
```

Which fails with `System.ArgumentException: Expected a public key Parameter name: publicParameter`.

My question is: How to get the public key from a private key?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to help from James K Polk, here is what I came up with

```
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GetKeyPairFromPrivateKey(AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey)
    {
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = null;
        if (privateKey is RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsa)
        {
            var pub = new RsaKeyParameters(false, rsa.Modulus, rsa.PublicExponent);
            keyPair = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(pub, privateKey);
        }
        else if (privateKey is Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters ed)
        {
            var pub = ed.GeneratePublicKey();
            keyPair = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(pub, privateKey);
        }
        else if (privateKey is ECPrivateKeyParameters ec)
        {
            var q = ec.Parameters.G.Multiply(ec.D);
            var pub = new ECPublicKeyParameters(ec.AlgorithmName, q, ec.PublicKeyParamSet);
            keyPair = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(pub, ec);
        }
        if (keyPair == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException($"The key type {privateKey.GetType().Name} is not supported.");

        return keyPair;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be very simple:

```
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair KeyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)reader.ReadObject();
```

Then:

```
var pubKey = KeyPair.public;
```

Comment: please show How to get the public key from a private key?

Comment: Just import the Private Key with your Pem-Reader. When transforming to "AsymmetricCipherKeyPair" the Public Key is generated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little clumsy with the Bouncycastle C# library but I think the way to do this is to explicitly make a new key object using the appropriate components of the private key. Example

```
// Make an rsa keypair for testing

var rand = new SecureRandom();
var keyGenParams = new RsaKeyGenerationParameters(
        new BigInteger("65537"), rand, 1024, 64
    );
var rsaKeyGen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
rsaKeyGen.Init(keyGenParams);
var rsaKeyPair = rsaKeyGen.GenerateKeyPair();
var rsaPriv = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)rsaKeyPair.Private;

// Make a public from the private

var rsaPub = new RsaKeyParameters(false, rsaPriv.Modulus, rsaPriv.PublicExponent);

// Try it out

var rsaKeyPair2 = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(rsaPub, rsaPriv);
```

The downside of this approach is that it requires a concrete instance of a specific kind of asymmetric key; it does not work with the abstract asymmetric key classes.

Comment: Thanks but the key has already been created, hence the use of PKCS #8.  Also, the key does not have to be RSA.

Comment: rsaPub is wrong.  The 3rd param should be `rsaPriv.PublicExponent`.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: Good catch. Fixed. Also, as I stated, it's not a generic solution. I chose RSA just to illustrate how to do it for RSA. Something similar will have to be done for every asymmetric key type that you want to do this for. You can make a utility method that does this for all the asymmetric key types you want to support.